# Disable OpenVPN Auto Reconnect

Tags: openvpn

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and use OpenVPN to connect to a client's VPN.  If I forget to disconnect the VPN and I'm not at my computer, it eventually disconnects and automatically tries to reconnect.  When it reconnects, it triggers 2 factor over and over and eventually locks me out for failed login attempts.  How do I disable the auto reconnection?

[image]

Comment: If you use an ovpn file, the reconnect setting may be there.

Comment: Asked here long ago with no accepted answer https://superuser.com/q/674552/471860  Personally I don't see a way without scripting external to openvpn, so following to learn.

Comment: I use nordvpn, they have their own client for that, and it is, now, working fine. autoconnect and killswitch are features. all command line now.